# Remove line of text from a Json file

Tags: json, discord, discord.py

I am programming an economic bot with items, inventory, currency and much more, but now when I sell my item in my inventory it is still there in the embed, but I want that when I sell my item and the number in the inventory is 0 that this is then no longer displayed in the inventory embed, so to speak, is removed from the Json file

My code for the sell command:

```
@client.command()
async def sell(ctx,item,amount = 1):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    res = await sell_this(ctx.author,item,amount)

    em1 = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}",
                        description="Das item konnte nicht in deinem Inventar gefunden werden",
                        color=0xe67e22)
    em1.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    em2 = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}",
                        description=f"Du hast keine {amount} {item} in deinem inventar",
                        color=0xe67e22)
    em2.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    em3 = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}",
                        description=f"Du hast das Item: **{item}** nicht in deinem Inventar",
                        color=0xe67e22)
    em3.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    em4 = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}",
                        description=f"Du hast {amount} {item} gekauft",
                        color=0xe67e22)
    em4.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

    if not res[0]:
        if res[1]==1:
            await ctx.send(embed=em1)
            return
        if res[1]==2:
            await ctx.send(embed=em2)
            return
        if res[1]==3:
            await ctx.send(embed=em3)
            return

    await ctx.send(embed=em4)

async def sell_this(user,item_name,amount,price = None):
    item_name = item_name.lower()
    name_ = None
    for item in mainshop:
        name = item["name"].lower()
        if name == item_name:
            name_ = name
            if price==None:
                price = 0.9* item["price"]
            break

    if name_ == None:
        return [False,1]

    cost = price*amount

    users = await get_bank_data()

    bal = await update_bank(user)


    try:
        index = 0
        t = None
        for thing in users[str(user.id)]["bag"]:
            n = thing["item"]
            if n == item_name:
                old_amt = thing["amount"]
                new_amt = old_amt - amount
                if new_amt < 0:
                    return [False,2]
                users[str(user.id)]["bag"][index]["amount"] = new_amt
                t = 1
                break
            index+=1
        if t == None:
            return [False,3]
    except:
        return [False,3]



    with open("Bank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    await update_bank(user,cost,"wallet")

    return [True,"Worked"]
```

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Use [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) to delete the item in question from the json data:

```py
    try:
        index = 0
        t = None
        for thing in users[str(user.id)]["bag"]:
            n = thing["item"]
            if n == item_name:
                old_amt = thing["amount"]
                new_amt = old_amt - amount
                if new_amt < 0:
                    return [False,2]
                elif new_amt == 0: # Check if amount is 0
                    del users[str(user.id)]["bag"][index] # Delete item from bag
                else:
                    users[str(user.id)]["bag"][index]["amount"] = new_amt
                t = 1
                break
            index+=1
        if t == None:
            return [False,3]
    except:
        return [False,3]
```

This completely removes the item and amount from the 'bag'.